# Is there a way to use insertMany and populate something for each inserted item in a single mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose insertMany to create multiple orders. In the same query I would like to populate the restaurant property for each order. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This has to be done by passing the already "populated" objects to your `insertMany` call. You can do this by maping the initial orders to the same object containing the additional "restaurant" property like in the following example:

```
const orders = [
  {
    orderName: 'orderA',
  },
  {
    orderName: 'orderB',
  },
  {
    orderName: 'orderC',
  },
];

orders.insertMany(
  orders.map(order => ({ ...order, restaurant: 'restaurantXY' }))
);
```

Comment: Will this really populate the restaurant object from Restaurant model as I am referencing that from the order object? I see you are manually adding the restaurant property?

Comment: @Alamin Shaikh, you may need to add ObjectId-s as references, instead of strings?

Comment: What do you mean by „will it be populated“? You are inserting documents here. Populating can take place when you are retrieving (reading) documents from the database, not when you are inserting it.